# Authentication?

Tags: security

How to authenticate web api in APIM?

What are best approaches to authenticate web API's and are the process that must be followed ?

Comment: Are you trying to use the certificate to authenticate the client making the request to APIM, or authenticate APIM to your backend API?  The first snippet you show is to authenticate the client and the second is to authenticate APIM to your backend API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two places in APIM where you may employ client certificate auth. One is between client and APIM service, another is between APIM service and backend. To do the former you would have to change your client that makes calls to APIM service to attach certificate with request. Once that's done you should be able to retrieve this certificate in expressions by context.Request.Certificate.

To use client certificate to authenticate APIM service with it's backend you have to upload certificate through management portal and assign it to API using either API settings or API policies directly.